# Skinning Entire Eclipse GUI, Not Just Code Window

Tags: java, eclipse

I have found some nice dark themes for editing code in Eclipse (screenshot below), but they only apply to the code window itself.  The package explorer and outline view are still white background.  It would be great if there was some way to make everything dark, even the toolbar at the top.  Is this possible?

Thanks,
Jonah

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, Eclipse uses SWT, which mixes pure-Java components with native components, and I think that that makes it impossible to apply such a change to the whole GUI. But maybe I 'm wrong.

Comment: That's a nice colour scheme :)

Comment: (... and this is one of the main reasons for which I prefer Swing to SWT)

Comment: (Aside: I've never understood why do people waste their time doing this kind of thing.  Who cares if Eclipse windows have "rounded corners with beveled underclings"?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customise the user interface by creating a new appearance. This functionality is integrated into Eclipse, and comes with the 'classic' VS as well as the modern one by default. See http://andrei.gmxhome.de/skins/index.html for a custom appearance. You can probably change the colours of the component backgrounds with your own :)

[image: High contrast VS]

Answer (score 2):

In short: no, not really. SWT doesn't include any kind of skinning capability. If your OS has window color preferences, much of the Eclipse GUI will respect them, but I wouldn't guarantee *all* would. But you could certainly try using your OS's facilities, and see how far you get with that.

Answer (score 2):

The *Juno release of Eclipse* (released 27 June 2012) makes it possible to change Eclipse's theme. The theme enables the possibility of changing every GUI color, even the toolbar at the top. The appearance of the editor was already possible. If you change both the theme and the editor's appearance with Eclipse Juno you can have a real nice looking dark theme.

[This post](http://eblog.chrononsystems.com/dark-eclipse-theme) has a simple 3 step proces to get a dark theme like this:
[image: dark-themed Eclipse Juno]

This will cost you less than 10 minutes to configure.